# Conditional Form elements submitting using jquery ajax in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm asking a question about conditional form field submitting using jquery and ajax in PHP, in my form there is two types of select box's (1. reference and 2. reference_info), in reference select box there two options (1. None, and 2. Friends) if user select 2nd option (Friends) then user must select option in reference_info select box.

```
// Submit Form
$('#add_new_user').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name        = $('#name').val();
    var age         = $('#age').val();
    var gender      = $('#gender').val();
    var address     = $('#cddress').val();
    var contact     = $('#contact').val();
    var reference   = $('#reference').val();
    var ref_info    = $('#reference_info').val();

    if(name != '' && age != '' && gender != '' && reference != '' && ref_info != ''){
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        /*$.ajax({
            url:"ajax.php",
            method:"post",
            data:formData,
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });*/
        alert(formData);
    }else{
        alert("Please fill required fields.");
    }
});
```

Form structure:
Reference select Box

```
<select name="reference" class="form-control" id="reference">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="1">None</option>
    <option value="2">Friends</option>
</select>
```

Reference Info select Box

```
<select name="reference_info" class="form-control" id="reference_info">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="1">Friend 1</option>
    <option value="2">Friend 2</option>
    <option value="3">Friend 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What issue are you facing? And don't paste code as a picture in the question please. Read [ask].

Comment: if(ref_info != 'Friends' && reference == '') return false;

Comment: @lovelace question is simple, if user select option (Friends) in reference select box, user must be select option in reference_info select box then form will submit

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar where i add this -> if(ref_info != 'Friends' && reference == '') return false; ?

Comment: @user12052529 before if condition

Comment: var errorcount = 0;
if(ref_info != 'Friends' && reference == '') errorcount++

if(errorcount == 0){
  if(name != '' && gender != '' && age != '' && ref_info != ''){
     // make ajax call here
  }
}

Comment: My question is when user select Friends in reference select box, he must select friend in reference_info select box

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar now post actual code instead of static image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204041/discussion-between-bhavik-gajjar-and-user12052529).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.do not post code image.

```
function friends_function() {
if(ref_info == '') {
    alert("please fill ref_info")
    return
 } 

 //here ajax function


}  

function none_ref_funtion() {
    //your normal ajax function
}






switch(reference) {
    case "friends":
    friends_function();
    break;
    case "none":
    none_ref_function();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#add_new_user').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name        = $('#name').val();
    var age         = $('#age').val();
    var gender      = $('#gender').val();
    var address     = $('#cddress').val();
    var contact     = $('#contact').val();
    var reference   = $('#reference').val();
    var ref_info    = $('#reference_info').val();

    var errorcount = 0; 
    if(reference == 'Friends' && ref_info == '') {
      errorcount++;
      alert("Please select ref info");
    }

    if(errorcount == 0){

     if(name != '' && age != '' && gender != '' && reference != ''){
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        /*$.ajax({
            url:"ajax.php",
            method:"post",
            data:formData,
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });*/
        alert(formData);
      }else{
        alert("Please fill required fields.");
     }
   }
});
```